# Regarding write_board and saving member_idx in the DB

Tags: php

I am trying to make a writing board and need to save ID value in the DB when the writer done its saving.
But my db shows only '0' member_idx and it looks my id session maintating is now working. 
I attach related code of mine, but please let me know if you need more codes which I've missed.

_this is my work_tree under htdocs of apache2 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLlbS.jpg)

this is login_check.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once ('../config.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB['host'], $DB['id'], $DB['pw'], $DB['db']);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

extract($_POST);

$q = "SELECT * FROM ap_member WHERE id='$user_id'";

$result = $mysqli->query($q);

if($result->num_rows==1) {
    $encrypted_pass = sha1($user_pass);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if( $row['pw'] == $encrypted_pass ) {
        $_SESSION['member_idx'] = $row['member_idx'];
        header('Location: '.$url['root'].'login_done.php');
    }
    else {
        echo 'wrong password';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'ID does not exist or invalid approach. Try again.';
}

if( $row['pw'] == $encrypted_pass ) {
        $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'YES';
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['member_idx'] = $row['member_idx'];
        header('Location: '.$url['root'].'login_done.php');
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'NO';
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
        header('Location: '.$url['root'].'login_done.php');
        exit();
    }

?>
```

_this is write.php

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/preset.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
?>

Write a Commment for anything please <br />
<form name ="write_form" method = "POST" action = "./write_check.php">
<input type="hidden" name="member_idx" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['member_idx'] ?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
    Title
    </td>
    <td>
            <input type ="text" name = "subject" size ="90">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Content
    </td>
    <td>
            <textarea name="content" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "저장">
</div>


</form>

<?php
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.php';
?>
```

_ and finally this is my DB what it looks like now

_+ here's my ap_bbs

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/preset.php';
?>

<?php

$reg_date = time();
$member_idx = $_SESSION['member_idx'];

$q = "INSERT INTO ap_bbs (member_idx, subject,content,reg_date) VALUES('$member_idx', '$subject', '$content', '$reg_date')";

$result = $mysqli->query($q);

if ($result==false) {
    $_SESSION['writing_status'] = 'NO';
}
else {
    $_SESSION['writing_status'] = 'YES';
}

$mysqli->close();

header('Location: '.$url['root'].'bbs/write_done.php');
exit();

?>
```

[image]

Comment: `extract()` in the global scope. **Nasty and insecure**

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: You had better show us the code that actually stored rows into `ap_bbs` as that is probably where the error is

Comment: `ap_bbs.doc_idx` does not seem to have been created as an `Auto Increment` column. Did you make the same mistake with the key to `ap_member`? That would explain why you always get a `0` in `ap_bbs.member_idx`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added at the last. will check and revise the insecure part quickly as you recommended.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've tried to give Auto Increment value when I make up my DB of ap_bbs, but wasn't able to locate or doesn't understand what it means and how to put it on my D.

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh shit, the A_I was acronyms of Auto increment. will add that character right away.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Changed Primary Key and Put the value of AI make it work. Thx